# `Uncaught ReferenceError: sap is not defined` after self-contained build with UI5 Tooling

Tags: typescript, sapui5, ui5-tooling

I have already built an application using SAPUI5 `1.108`. When launch the application locally (`npm run start`), everything works as expected.
However, I didn't notice that the system where the application is to be deployed into does not have the SAPUI5 version `1.108` but the version `1.71`. Since the latter one lacks some features that the former has, the application won't run.
Therefore, I wanted to create a self-contained build of the application and deploy a project built this way. Unfortunately, after building the application this way, when I run the `index.html` file, the application doesn't even work locally.

When I try to build a self-contained application, none of the following give a working result:
`ui5 build self-contained --include-all-dependencies --clean-dest --dest dist`
`ui5 build self-contained --include-all-dependencies --config=ui5.yaml --clean-dest --dest dist`

The error I'm getting in the browser console:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: sap is not defined at sap-ui-custom.js:1:1`

I've noticed that the `resources` directory in the built application does not contain the `sap-ui-core.js` file, but I assume that this itself is not a problem as the path in the `index.html` is updated to the `sap-ui-custom.js` file.

[image: The file explorer in Visual Studio Code showing the contents of the dist/resources directory]

The `@ui5/cli` version I am using is `3.7.0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure all relevant **framework dependencies** are available during the build (especially `sap.ui.core`). They should be declared in the `ui5.yaml`. You can check what dependencies UI5 Tooling will use by executing `ui5 ls --flat`.

If this does not help you in finding the issue, I'd propose to raise a bug report at https://github.com/SAP/ui5-tooling/issues/new/choose

If possible, provide your whole project. If not, provide at least the full build log (add the `--verbose` flag), the content of your `ui5.yaml`, the `index.html` from the build result and the first couple of lines of the generated `sap-ui-custom.js`.